# Error Code Handling

Tags: c, error-handling

Are there any standards for error code handling? What I mean by this is not how a particular error event is handled but what is actually returned in the process. An example of this would be when an error in opening a file is identified. While the `open()` function may return its own value, the function that called the `open()` function may return a different value.

Comment: Standard C usually uses errno. See [man 3 errno](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/errno.3.html). Otherwise it's application specific.

Comment: There are no question marks in your post. What are you actually asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think ther's a standard, all errors must be detected and handled (the caller should always handle errors).
in Unix in general:

- the standard C library for exemple always `return -1 on fail` and **set the global variable errno** to the correct value.
- Some libraries for example `return NULL` for **inexistant** field rather than **aborting**.
- You should always return as much useful information as possible.

Hope this help.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds entirely context dependent to me. In some cases it's even advisable to just `abort()` the whole process. The failing function is called from a program or library using its own coding standards, you should probably adhere to that.